# Having a button perform 2 jobs

Tags: java, android

Is there a way of having 1 single button perform more then 1 job?
 Lets say the user clicks on a button called 4 that displays a textview showing the number 4,
 can the user then press the button 4 again and display the string "four". 
Can you some how use switch() cases to do it?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {               
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    add = add +4;
    display.setText("2 + 2 =" + add);
}
});
```

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what your question is. Could you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a Boolean variable to keep track of states (please make this global to an activity so that function may access it). i.e.:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(flag){
           add = add +4;
           display.setText("2 + 2 =" + add);
        }
        else display.setText("Something else");
        flag=!flag;
}
```

Comment: By "global", do you mean "class member"?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I hope the above is what you are looking for. Yes I mean class member. I hate terminologies -_-

Comment: you have to maintain state and one way of maintaining state can be as mentioned by Akshay

Comment: i dont know what to put in flag im pretty crap at java logic >_<, thanx for helping though